# "Four and one half feet to an inch" or "Four and half feet to an inch"

Tags: numbers

To mention the scale of a map, which is more natural and formal, "Four and one half feet to an inch" or "Four and half feet to an inch" ?

Comment: Four and **a** half feet to an inch

Answer (score 1):

In writing, I would use *"four and **one** half feet.*

In speech, I would say *"four and **one** half feet* if I want to emphasize the number - e.g. I am telling someone the conversion for the first time.

If I am referring to the conversion or speaking quickly, I might say *"four and **a** half feet.*

> [*spoken*] He gave me a map of the city that was four and one half feet to the inch.....  Can you believe that?  How am I supposed to carry a map with a scale of four and a half feet to the inch!  The map was huge!  ....Four and one half feet to the inch.

Caveat: I am an engineer in the U.S.  My demographic has a reputation for being very precise with numbers, so it may be the case that others use *"four and **one** half* a little less frequently than me.   The point is that either is acceptable, and the choice between them is a matter of style.

EDIT:  In response to comments.

- Fractions in ratios are a little awkward, but not totally unheard of.  For instance, in describing [road grades](https://books.google.com/books?id=MCNKAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA119&lpg=RA1-PA119&dq=%22and%20a%20half%20feet%20to%20the%22&source=bl&ots=wBwpNot3pb&sig=VWK9yEBR2AUA3eSvi-sQybB4wkg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi43pnAxcbMAhVFpB4KHbHtAo8Q6AEINTAH#v=onepage&q=%22and%20a%20half%20feet%20to%20the%22&f=false) or [streambed slopes](https://books.google.com/books?id=ivtLAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA52&dq=%22and%20a%20half%20feet%20to%20the%20mile%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuk_e7xsbMAhXhg6YKHZc0DSsQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22and%20a%20half%20feet%20to%20the%20mile%22&f=false), they pop up. The OP asked about scale ratios in maps, and I agree that that is a peculiar scale to use, but mostly because it makes for huge maps.  Maybe in an architectural drawing?
- User3169 suggests I point out that I switched the OP's *feet to **an** inch* to *feet to **the** inch.*  Using *to **the*** is much more common, at least in the U.S.

Comment: It's probably also worth mentioning that this is not likely to come up... using fractions in a scale ratio is just a mess.

Comment: @T.J.L. I agree - I was trying to formulate a comment about why you should use 1::54 notation instead, but I started to get all Engineery and it got too far afield from English, so I didn't hit the submit button.

Comment: You might emphasize "to *the* inch" (as you wrote) which is a better option than "to *an* inch" that was used in the question.

Answer (score 1):

"Four and one half" is grammatical, but it is **much** less common than "four and a half". ("Four and half" is not grammatical).

My intuition also says that "Four and one half" is American, and I would not expect to find it in British English.

Looking at GloWbE (the corpus of global web-based English) bears out my expectations. "and one half" occurs 376 times in the corpus, with over 100 being in US sources, 59 British, and 50 Canadian.

"And a half" occurs 39482 times (more than 100 times as often), and GB sources slightly outnumber US sources (8563, 8120 respectively).